# Why vertices are changing their position during Weight Paint Mode?

Tags: weight-painting

I am new to Blender. I am making a MineCraft character.
In the Weight Paint Mode, When i am assigning weight to vertices they are changing their positions. Like, a small change in global z axis or along x axis.How can i solve this problem.[![enter image description here][1]][1]
Thankyou.

ImageBeforeWeightPainting:: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7xiG.png
 ImageAfterWeightPainting::   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhDpy.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via weight painting, you increase or decrease influence of the bones on vertices. That's why they change position. If f.ex. some bone influences a vertice with strength of 0 nothing happens, but when you give this vertice weight of 1 it starts to be influenced by this bone with strength of 1 and it's moving closer to it. This is normal and expected behaviour. Although your example looks weird.Could you provide the .blend?

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. I got it. Yes i will.

Comment: http://wikisend.com/download/548744/41-minecraft-char_3.blend

Comment: This armature is basically perfect for this character, so just unparent it and delete Armature modifier from Happy Tounge mesh and parent it again by selecting mesh first and then Armature, pressing CTRL+P and choosing With Automatic Weights. You won't need no weight painting then.

Comment: Okay, i got the problem. The problem was that the "face-jaw" bone is not correctly at its position.When i have reset its position, there is no change in the position of vertices(In weight Paint mode). Thankyou mate.